# Maven plugin - searching net.abc in repository and should search net/abc

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven plugin defined as this in the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

When I run mvn, I get the following message:

> > [WARNING] repository metadata for: '...' could not be retrieved from repository...
> >
> > Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://10.1.1.102/net.abc/poms/maven-metadata.xml

When I point my web browser at `http://10.1.1.102/`, the file exists in `http://10.1.1.102/net/abc`, not `http://10.1.1.102/net.abc`

How do I specify the gorupId so that it searches the correct directory?

**Edit**:

As requested, here is the whole error:

```
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'snapshot net.abc:abc-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: DEV2016 due to an error: Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://10.1.1.102/net.abc/poms/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Repository 'DEV2016' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] A required plugin was not found: Plugin could not be found - check that the goal name is correct: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
```

Comment: The error pasted is not related to the question you asked. Because the group id which you have mentioned is right. It will search through the folder net/abc. Can you please post the complete error?

Comment: Http error code 503 means Service unavailable. Check the server connection individually as well as manually by reaching it. Also check the firewall(iptables).

Comment: I can get to it just fine via a web browser, which is how I know that the url with `net.abc` does not exist and that the URL `net/abc` is the correct one.

Comment: @mikeb What is the correct full URL to access to the artifact?

Comment: http://10.1.1.102/net/abc

Comment: If your GA is `<groupId>net.abc</groupId><artifactId>abc-maven-plugin</artifactId>` the repo path should be `/net/abc/abc-maven-plugin/`. So, It's not only `/net.abc/` which is mysterious, it's also `/poms/`. What is the exact command line when you run `mvn`? Which repository is it?  Which web server is it? Is there any kind of redirection/proxying/virtualisation defined on either of them?

Answer (score 0):

See [POM Reference, Maven Coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) regarding the repository path:

> - **groupId:** ... When stored within a repository, the group acts much like the Java packaging structure does in an operating system. The dots are replaced by OS specific directory separators (such as '/' in Unix) which becomes a relative directory structure from the base repository. In the example given, the `org.codehaus.mojo` group lives within the directory `$M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo`.